# Export Excel Range to PDF but fill out entire PDF page without page margins

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export

I want to export an Excel-range to PDF, and I manage that with the VBA function workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat.

My problem is the when I open the PDF, the exported range has not filled out the entire PDF-page, maybe because of the page margins on the sides, tops and bottoms of a standard PDF page.

I want to export the range, but at the same time fill out the entire PDF-page.

This is my macro right now. I am exporting range B2-I103.

```
Sub printToPDF()


ActiveSheet.Range("B2:I103").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=ActiveSheet.Range("K21").Value & ActiveSheet.Range("K23").Value, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
openafterpublish:=True


End Sub
```

What I am getting is this: [image: Picture of PDF]

I do want to get rid of the white margins surrounding the picture and fill out the whole page.

Solutions are well appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer but is too long for a comment ... hence added as an answer ... hope it helps get you going in the right direction.

`ExportAsFixedFormat` borrows the settings used by the `PageSetup` object of the relevant Worksheet. As such, if you do this ...

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .TopMargin = 0
    .BottomMargin = 0
    .LeftMargin = 0
    .RightMargin = 0
End With
```

... first then you will minimize the margins ... though when I test it does not eliminate them. You can maybe have a play around with the other `PageSetup` properties which you can see here [PageSetup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup) to see if you can eliminate them.

Comment: Thank you. I will explore this and report back to you someday.